# If string does not equal const char break out of while loop

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem breaking out of this while loop in my code. If the user is done entering items I want them to press q to exit. This does not work, q gets entered by the user and the loop is not broken. If there is also a better way to do this that would be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CashRegister.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

CashRegister::CashRegister(void)
{
}

CashRegister::~CashRegister(void)
{
}

void CashRegister::addItem(void)
{
string temp;
int k = 0;
int exit = 0;
CashRegister item[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i)
{
    item[i].price = 0.00;
}

cout << "Enter price of items. Up to 10 maximum\n" << endl;

while(item[9].price != 0.00 || temp != "q")
{
    cout << "Enter price of item number " << k + 1 << "\n" << endl;
    cin >> temp;
    cout << temp << endl;
    double tempPrice = (double)atof(temp.c_str());
    item[k].price = tempPrice;
    cout << "Price of item number " << k + 1 << " is $" << item[k].price << endl;
    ++k;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your while loop needs to read:

```
while(item[9].price != 0.00 && temp != "q")
```

The loop needs to continue while both conditions are true, so you need to say `&&` not `||`.

Comment: Sorry misclick, my loop seems to be ending prematurely now.

Comment: Hmm, is `item[9].price` ever `0.00`?  That seems like the only reason that would happen.

Comment: When I do an if statement to check if it is 0.00, it does come out as 0.00. I just changed my code to `while(item[9].price <= 0.00)` and everything works now.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(item[9].price != 0.00 || temp != "q")
```

Consider what this is saying.  "*Loop while price isn't 0 **or** temp isn't "q".*"  Now consider what has to occur for this to stop looping.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this to break loop :

```
while(item[9].price != 0.00 && temp != "q")
{
  // ur stuff
}
```

Loop will iterate because **item[9].price**  will contain some value other then 0.00